# TaskPane does not draw, appears blank

Tags: c#, windows-7, vsto, outlook-2007

I discovered a very specific issue with modal Inspectors in Windows 7 systems running Outlook 2007. I'm developing an addin that places a ribbon button and UserControl (in the form of a taskPane) into the email-compose window.

The issue is: with that specific setup, (with Outlook 2007 already running) when the user attempts to launch an email-compose window externally (this can be through 'send via email' in Adobe Reader or many other applications).

The TaskPane that appears appended to the right-side of the form has a semi-random chance to not draw and simply appear blank.

I have prepared a sample solution that trims down all the unnecessary fat, if you look in the bin>debug folder, there is a ready-to-run sample to demonstrate the issue

http://www.mediafire.com/file/ctmsbba09n6u0vp/MissingPaneExample.zip

Answer (score 1):

If it draws blank, will it draw if you resize the custom task pane?

I have had issues around it not drawing in certain scenario's, and my work around has been to put a this.Width++; in the load event of the control, quite a hack, but has worked for me in the past.

Comment: +1 I just had to do this workaround. Do you know why after an `InitializeComponent();` and the VSTO (floating) Pane is visible its controls have Width=0 and Height=0?